# What is the expected number of hops in a shortest path?

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading the [Wikipedia entry for Yen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm) and under "Time complexity" a statement is made regarding the length $l$ of the spur paths in graphs with $\mathrm{N}$ nodes.

> In a condensed graph, the expected value of $l$ is $\mathcal{O}(\log \mathrm{N})$.

From the given [citation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm#cite_note-4) I can only find results from an experiment with $50$ nodes that aligns with this claim, which is not convincing. Is there a more rigorous proof, or perhaps an obvious explanation, that this indeed is applicable to all condensed graphs?